# How do aminoacyl-tRNA synthases distinguish between similar amino acids?

Tags: molecular-biology, rna, amino-acids, translation

How do aminoacyl tRNA synthases recognize the right amino acid for their tRNA? What is the structural reason behind the selective recognition? I have difficulty in seeing how, for example, leucine and isoleucine can be selectively recognized by different binding pockets when they exhibit similar hydrophobicity, molecular volume etc.

Comment: *"it seems a little bit absurd"*... why? enzymes can even distinguish stereoisomers of the **same** molecule, let alone different molecules.

Comment: I have rewritten the title so it reflects the question and tightened the wording .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aminoacyl-tRNA sythetases are highly specific to their corresponding amino acid. First, the activation site, where the amino acid binds, constitutes a complex network of intermolecular interactions. For example, threonine, catalyzed by  threonyl-tRNA synthetase, is very similar to valine and serine. Valine has a methyl group instead of the hydroxy group of threonine, and serine, on the other side, has no additional methyl side group. Uniquely to threonyl-tRNA synthetase, it contains a Zn<sup>2+</sup> ion that exhibits an interaction structure specific to threonine. Nonetheless, the threonyl-tRNA synthetase could still be mischarged with serine because the zinc ion site is not specific enough, leading to 1% mischarged tRNAs. For this purpose, aminoacyl-tRNA synthetases have a second, *editing* site that proofreads the charged tRNA.  The editing site can recognize serine and cleave it from the tRNA.

**Figure:** Interaction network of the activation site of the threonyl-tRNA synthetase in *A. pernix*. The  threonine-AMP  is shown in green.

[image]

**Sources:**

<sup>a</sup> Berg JM, Tymoczko JL, Stryer L. Biochemistry. 5th edition. New York: W H Freeman; 2002. Section 29.2, Aminoacyl-Transfer RNA Synthetases Read the Genetic Code. Available from: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK22356/

<sup>b</sup> Nagaoka, Yoshiyuki, et al. "EVOLUTION AND tRNA RECOGNITION OF THREONYL-tRNA SYNTHETASE FROM AN EXTREME THERMOPHILIC ARCHAEON, Aeropyrum pernix K1." Viva Origino 1.31 (2003), http://www.origin-life.gr.jp/3101/3101062/3101062.html